# Mocking BLE Characteristic Write with MockRxAndroidBle

Tags: android, unit-testing, rxandroidble

I'm writing a JUnit test for writing data to a BLE characteristic using the MockRxAndroidBle.  The characteristics are being added to the mock device using the `addService(UUID, List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>)` method on the `DeviceBuilder`.  The characteristics themselves are being created using the CharacteristicBuilder.  When the test is run, it fails with the message `java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setValue in android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details."`

The referenced link indicates that default values should be used in unit tests.

`testOptions {
      unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}`

Enabling that allows the test to get past in setup of the characteristic but the fails when attempting to write the characteristic.  The exception at this point is a `BleCharacteristicNotFoundException`.  Upon closer inspection it seems that the `BluetoothGattService` instance in `RxBleDeviceServices` returns null when retrieving the characteristic by UUID.  The debugger also shows that the service does not have any characteristics and the list is null.  I believe that null is the default value for this internal list.

Is there a way to create a JUnit test that mocks writing to a characteristic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the test with Roboelectric. So add this to your unit test class definition

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)